# name of upload files

Tags: python, django

When registered user upload some files as PDF to MEDIA_ROOT (named usermedia directory)
document is saved in directory as 12345676542.pdf
this number is users OIB number which give when registered

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f,wusr):
    nname = "%s.%s" % (str(wusr.oib), f.name.split(".")[1])
    print nname
    destination = open('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT, nname), 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

but when the user wants to upload another document this document is saved as previous document

How to set when user want upload another file to geth file named as 12345676542-1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You either need to maintain a data store of what the last index used by that user was or search the file system for existing files for that user and find the first unused (or last used) index, then create your new file with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a solution. **Keep in mind I haven't tested this, so there might be syntax errors. Treat this as a suggestion.**

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f,wusr):
    nname = "%s.%s" % (str(wusr.oib), f.name.split(".")[1])
    nname = unique(nname)
    destination = open('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT, nname), 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()

# Return unique file name in format <filename>-<num>.<ext>
def unique(path):
    import os.path
    num = 0
    newpath = path

    def fileExists(path):
        return os.path.isfile(path)

    # Keep incrementing until an unique filename is reached
    while fileExists(newpath):
        num += 1
        pieces = path.rsplit('.', 1)
        newpath = "%s-%d.%s" % (pieces[0], num, pieces[1])

    return newpath
```

The `unique` function would generate a new file name guaranteed to be unique. This particular solution of checking the disk for every interval could be problematic when you reach a high number of identically named uploads. If the speed of this solution turns out to be a problem, just list all files in the directory to begin with and perform the above operations on that string instead. That will reduce the number of disk operations from *x* to 1

Comment: well but i dont know how to integrate it to my app, are something missing?

Comment: The above example is just an edit of the code in your question. You should be able to integrate the example into the exact same spot from which you copied the code in your question. It's just an additional function called `unique` that you run on your file name before you use it, I really can't get any clearer than that

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to check for existing files until it finds an appropriate unused filename. Something like this:

```
import os

filename = base_filename = '123456765432'
ext = '.pdf'
suffix = 0
while os.path.exists(filename+ext):
    suffix += 1
    filename = '%s-%d' % (base_filename, suffix)
```